# How to check the integrity of a downloaded MacOS X installer?

Tags: macos, install, mac-appstore

A Sierra installer I downloaded last week was corrupted. It wasn't obvious at first since I was able to create a USB installer and the USB stick booted fine. But after an hour of proceeding I had issues in MacOS installation process, I got a message that says my installer was corrupted.
I downloaded it again and after one more hour it is working fine.

When downloading Linux ISOs, most (perhaps all) distributions provides an MD5/SHA1 code so I can check my downloaded copy with those.

So is there way to check for the integrity of Mac AppStore downloads? I'm not so concerned with small downloads but very with 1+GB ones which could waste hours of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Apple KB: [Mac OS X: How to verify a SHA-1 digest](https://support.apple.com/HT201259)
*[emphasis mine]*

> **Learn how to verify a SHA-1 digest (also known as a checksum).**
>
> Important: Verifying the SHA-1 of a software update is optional; it is
>   provided on Apple software updates for those individuals who want to
>   verify the authenticity of an update.
>
> **Note: For updates delivered by Automatic Software Update, SHA-1 digest verification is performed automatically for you.**
>
> To verify a manually-downloaded software update from Apple Downloads,
>   which contains a SHA-1 digest, perform the following steps:
>
> - Open Terminal (located in /Applications/Utilities).
> - Type the following at the Terminal prompt:   `openssl sha1 [full path to file]`

Which would appear to conclude that Apple doesn't maintain a public list of checksums for App Store versions.
However, there is an independent list maintained at https://github.com/drduh/macOS-Security-and-Privacy-Guide/blob/master/InstallESD_Hashes.csv for just the InstallESD components themselves.